# ssh-agent doesn't work however eval+ssh-add does, why?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

I have 3 servers: (a), (b) and (c).

Server (a) and (c) have server's (b) public key inside authorized_keys file.

I try to access server (c) throughout ssh connection to server (b) from server (a).

> (a) ---> (b) ---> (c)

Using:

```
ssh-agent
ssh -A <command>
```

Fails! with

> Permission denied (publickey)

However using:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
ssh -A <command>
```

Succeeds.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utility `ssh-agent`, when run alone, will have no effect at all on private key forwarding, as stated in man page:

> If a command (and optional arguments) is given, this is executed as a subprocess of
> the agent.  The agent exits automatically when the command given on the command line
> terminates

Since you don't provide a command, the subprocess is terminated at the beginning of `ssh-agent` execution, meaning - no action is performed.

Your solution is to pass `command` to the `ssh-agent` like that:

```
ssh-agent ssh -A <command>
```